# window become close without form being submitted

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer

I have a simple `javaScript` like:

```
function updateAndClose()
{
    submit();
    closeWindow();
}
```

`submit()` method submit a specific form
`closeWindow();` just close the current window and reload parent and others.

```
<img name="modifyAndCloseButton" src="img.gif" alt="Modify and close" title="Modify and close" style="cursor:hand " onclick="updateAndClose();" />
```

It almost works ok.

But sometimes window just become closed and the form is not submitted.

Is there any possibility that the `closeWindow();` will be called without the form submitted.?

BTW: I have to support from IE9 to IE11
and also compatible me.

Comment: no body to response :(

Answer (score 0):

As no one responding I figured out something. Let me know if I am wrong.

`submit();` is being called always before the `closeWindow();`

But when (not always) the form having large number of data it's taking a while to build up the full `request body` for `POST` request after the `submit()` being called.
In the mean time window being closed and reloaded. That's why some times request being lost and not being send completely to the server